# Loading animated interactive content in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: mobile, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I  have an **animated interactive** quiz at a URL which i want to load in my app.The URL is
`http://some-link/story.html` . Its an HTML file although the content is animated and interactive . but when i load it, then nothing but only blank appears.I am testing this using cordova on a device with Android 4.3
I am using this for loading the animation

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
config: {
    id: 'MyPanel',
    itemId: 'MyPanel',
    scrollable: true,
    listeners: [
        {
            fn: 'onMyPanelActivate',
            event: 'activate'
        }
    ]
},    onMyPanelActivate: function(newActiveItem, container, oldActiveItem, eOpts) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        //local path of your html file
        url: 'http://some-link/story.html',
        success : function(response) {
           Ext.getCmp('MyPanel').setHtml(response.responseText);
        },
        failure : function(response) {  
            var text = response.responseText;
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', text, Ext.emptyFn);            }
    });
}});
```

II tried to load it in Ext.Video but still nothing appears. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that this will load a HTML content at a particular URL but if there are images also on that HTML page and they have relative paths(../images/this.jpg), then this method wont load those images.

SO if i load my page on an Iframe, then it would load properly. BUt again, swf animation wont work on newer versions of Android because there is no flash support available.